# "Merge" two sparse matrices based on column names (in separate list)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have two sparse matrices like the following:

import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

```
m1_colnames = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 't', 'y']
m1 = csr_matrix(np.array([[1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0], [1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0]]))

m2_colnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
m2 = csr_matrix(np.array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 0]]))
```

Essentially what I want to do (in pandas terms) is merge by column name, to get a final sparse matrix that is of size 11 (11 unique column names) by 4 (4 rows).

However, I cannot convert to pandas then back, as my real dataset is over 1000000 rows by 100000 columns (sparse matrices).

How can this be done? I would need a final list of column names so I know the order of things in the merged sparse matrix.

Thanks,
Jack

EDIT:

Desired output:

```
final_colnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 't', 'y']
final_m = csr_matrix(np.array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5], [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 5]]))
```

Way of doing desired in pandas, though I am looking for a method without pandas:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(m1.A, columns = m1_colnames)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(m2.A, columns = m2_colnames)

final_df = pd.concat(df1, df2)
final_df = final_df.fillna(0)

final_sparse = csr_matrix(final_df.values)
final_colnames = final_df.columns
```

`final_sparse` and `final_colnames` is what I am looking for.

Comment: Can you, please, provide expected result?

Comment: @LevZakharov Updated, please see above.

Comment: There's nothing in `scipy.sparse` or `numpy` to merge columns by name.  Some mix of python list, set, and sort, and possibly numpy unique etc will be required to come up with the new column indices for each matrix.

Answer (score 2):

### basic sparse merger

```
In [503]: m1_colnames = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'e', 't', 'y']
     ...: m1 = sparse.coo_matrix(np.array([[1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0], [1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0]]))
     ...: m2_colnames = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']
     ...: m2 = sparse.coo_matrix(np.array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 0
     ...: ]]))

In [504]: m1
Out[504]: 
<2x6 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [505]: m2
Out[505]: 
<2x9 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 10 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
```

The key attributes of `m1` are:

```
In [506]: m1.data
Out[506]: array([1, 2, 4, 5, 1, 2, 4, 5])
In [508]: m1.row
Out[508]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
In [509]: m1.col
Out[509]: array([0, 1, 3, 4, 0, 1, 3, 4], dtype=int32)
```

Similarly for `m2`.

Based on your column names criteria, you just need to come up with a new set of `data`, `row`, and `col` arrays that define the merged matrices.

Since you are merging by columns, `row` and `data` values will be unchanged and can be concatenated

```
m3row  = np.concatenate((m1.row, m2.row))
m3data = np.concatenate((m1.data, m2.data))
```

creating the `m3col` will be more complicated since it's based on your column names criteria.  For illustration purposes I'll just append `m2` after `m1` (e.g. `hstack`)

```
In [515]: m3col = np.concatenate((m1.col, m2.col+6))
     ...: 
     ...: m3 = sparse.coo_matrix((m3data, (m3row, m3col)))

In [516]: m3
Out[516]: 
<2x14 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 18 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [517]: m3.A
Out[517]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5]])
```

### corrected rows

On rereading it looks like you want to put each matrix in separate rows, so something like this might be better

```
In [520]: m3row  = np.concatenate((m1.row, m2.row+2))
     ...: m3data = np.concatenate((m1.data, m2.data))
     ...: m3col  = np.concatenate((m1.col, m2.col+2))
     ...: shape = (4,11)

In [522]: m3 = sparse.coo_matrix((m3data, (m3row, m3col)), shape=shape)
In [523]: m3
Out[523]: 
<4x11 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.int64'>'
    with 18 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [524]: m3.A
Out[524]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 0]])
```

As requested in a comment, showing the desired matrix will help.  We don't want to guess. Plus you should be doing the real work.

### merging columns

It took some fiddling but I think I've come up with a reasonable column grouping approach.  `sparse` and `numpy` dont' have any thing quite like `pandas` for this.

Running your code produced:

```
In [622]: final_sparse.A
Out[622]: 
array([[1., 2., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 5., 0.],
       [1., 2., 0., 0., 4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 5., 0.],
       [1., 2., 0., 0., 4., 0., 4., 5., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 2., 0., 0., 4., 0., 4., 5., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

First collect the names, and get a unique (sorted) list:

```
In [623]: colnames=[]
In [624]: for col in [m1_colnames, m2_colnames]:
     ...:     colnames.extend(col)
     ...:     
In [625]: unames = np.unique(colnames)
In [626]: unames
Out[626]: array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 't', 'y'], dtype='<U1')
```

which should be the same as the pandas:

```
In [627]: final_colnames
Out[627]: Index(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 't', 'y'], dtype='object')
```

Finding `m1_colnames` in `unames` could be done with lists, but fortunatly `np.searchsorted` works just as well:

```
In [631]: np.searchsorted(unames, m1_colnames)
Out[631]: array([ 0,  1,  3,  4,  9, 10])
```

which can then be used to map the original `m1.col` onto the new matrix:

```
In [632]: _[m1.col]
Out[632]: array([0, 1, 4, 9, 0, 1, 4, 9])
```

So for all matrices:

```
In [633]: alist = []
In [634]: for n, col in zip([m1_colnames, m2_colnames],[m1.col, m2.col]):
     ...:     alist.append(np.searchsorted(unames, n)[col])  
In [635]: alist
Out[635]: [array([0, 1, 4, 9, 0, 1, 4, 9]), array([0, 1, 4, 6, 7, 0, 1, 4, 6, 7])]
In [636]: m3col = np.hstack(alist)
In [637]: m3data.shape
Out[637]: (18,)
In [638]: m3col.shape    # sanity check
Out[638]: (18,)
```

build the sparse matrix as before:

```
In [639]: m3 = sparse.coo_matrix((m3data, (m3row, m3col)), shape=shape)
In [640]: m3.A
Out[640]: 
array([[1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 0, 4, 0, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0]])
```

test

```
In [641]: np.allclose(m3.A, final_sparse.A)
Out[641]: True
```

Comment: I am sorry, I updated my question with the desired output along with a way of doing it using pandas so the idea is clear. I am sorry for being unclear earlier.

Comment: I've come up with a column merger.  Not the simplest but it seems to make good use of Python and numpy tools.